# I've installed forecast package in R along with dependencies but still get error 'could not find function tsclean'

Tags: r, forecastr

I m getting an error ->

```
library('forecast')
library('tseries')
library('fpp')

count_ts = ts(daily_data[, c('cnt')])
daily_data$clean_cnt = tsclean(count_ts)
```

> Error: could not find function "tsclean"

please suggest a solution

Comment: Any message when you load the library (`library(forecast)`)?

Comment: @R18 i just get a warning > library('forecast')
Warning message:
package ‘forecast’ was built under R version 3.3.3

Comment: @MarcoSandri - i tried to install it and got message....> installed.packages('forecast')
     Package LibPath Version Priority Depends Imports LinkingTo Suggests Enhances License License_is_FOSS
     License_restricts_use OS_type Archs MD5sum NeedsCompilation Built

Comment: What about if you type `?tsclean` ?

Comment: @PravinWagh So, no problem with the library (only a warning), . . . It is strange. What about what Marco asks?

Comment: It's working now...thanks guys